# Looping a select statement in asp clasic

Tags: asp-classic, dreamweaver

How do I loop selected records in asp classic without using the Dreamweaver repeat region.

```vb
<%
Dim rs_pic
Dim rs_pic_cmd
Dim rs_pic_numRows

Set rs_pic_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rs_pic_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_viva_web_STRING
rs_pic_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.users_pics ORDER BY u_pic_id DESC" 
rs_pic_cmd.Prepared = true
rs_pic_cmd.Parameters.Append rs_pic_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 5, 1, -1, rs_pic__lastmsg) ' adDouble

Set rs_pic = rs_pic_cmd.Execute
rs_pic_numRows = 0
%>
```

i know the repeat region does it simple but i want to know if there's a way u can loop it in the select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Do` loop?

```vb
Set rs_pic = rs_pic_cmd.Execute

Do While Not rs_pic.EOF
  'Access the record values here
  Response.Write "u_pic_id = " & rs_pic("u_pic_id").Value
  'Move to next record in the Recordset
  rs_pic.MoveNext()
Loop
```

Another approach which is more efficient then using `ADODB.Recordset` to iterate through the records is using a 2 Dimensional Array.

```vb
Set rs_pic = rs_pic_cmd.Execute

'If we have data convert it to an array.
If Not rs_pic.EOF Then data = rs_pic.GetRows()
'Close and release Recordset object
Call rs_pic.Close()
Set rs_pic = Nothing

'Use Array to iterate the data
If IsArray(data) Then
  'Get number of rows
  rows = UBound(data, 2)
  For row = 0 To rows
    'Return first column of current row.
    Response.Write data(0, row)
  Next
Else
  Response.Write "No records to display"  
End If
```